# What is all the real numbers $p,q$ such that $\int_0^1 x^p(-\ln x)^q \,dx$ is finite?

Tags: real-analysis

Dear reader of my question. I am stuck with this question. I don't know if I am thinking in the right way. Could you kindly help?

**Here is the question:**

What is all the real numbers $p,q$ such that $\int_0^1 x^p(-\ln x)^q \,dx$ is finite?

Below is my thought:

I think since $\ln q$ is negative infinity when x approaches $0$ from right hand side. We only need to consider the interval near $0$.

And if $q\le 0$, the $(-\ln x)^q$ is finite on $[0,1]$, $x^p$ is finite for $p \ge 0$. Then the integral is finite on $1 \le 0, p \ge 0$.

The other cases the integral is infinite.

Is that right?

Thanks very much!

Comment: You need to consider the behavior of $(-\ln(x))$ near $1$, what if $q<0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change variables to $x=e^{-y}$, so $dx = -e^{-y} dy$. Then
$$ \int_0^1 x^p (-\log{x})^q \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} y^{q} e^{-(p+1)y} \, dy. $$
Now, the two areas to be careful of are near $0$ and near $\infty$. The integrand is positive, so the integral is only finite if we can split it into pieces that are finite.

Near $0$, $e^{-py} \sim 1$, so the integral is only finite here if $p>0$, else it is bounded below by a multiple of $\int_{\varepsilon}^1 x^{-1} \, dx$, which diverges as $\varepsilon \to 0$.

For large $x$, $x^{q-1} e^{-(p+1)x} \to 0$ if $p>-1$. Further, if $p=-1$, the integrand is larger than a multiple of $x^{-1}$, so again the integral diverges, since $\int_1^{N} \frac{dx}{x} \to \infty$ as $N \to \infty$.

Therefore putting everything together, you need $p>-1$ and $q>-1$.